music-app-programming tag
I noticed this new tag: music-app-programming and I wonder:

do we really need it?
how about something more general? E.g. music-programming or similar?


We have an [algorithmic-composition] tag, maybe that would be close enough.

@ElementsInSpace "Algorithmic-composition" usually refers to the use of an algorithm to generate music. I take "music-app-programming" to refer to the creation of a music-related software application. Arguable the latter doesn't belong here in the first place, but I do think it's a distinct subject either way.


We definitely don't need it - that was the only question with it, and the question was not asking about application programming at all. (So I have edited it to remove the tag, which will become deleted automatically soon)
Maybe, but probably not yet - tags only become relevant when there is a need for them, ie a number of questions that would all benefit from it.

